# how is one PHP file is using the class provided by annother

Tags: php, oop

I need to do a task involving a PHP class and some sample code which is supposed to run the class. code bellow.

autoloader.php

```
<?php

/**
 * A basic PSR style autoloader
 */
class AutoLoader
{
    protected $dir;
    protected $ext;

    public function __construct($dir, $ext = '.php')
    {
        $this->dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
        $this->ext = $ext;
    }

    public static function register($dir, $ext = '.php')
    {
        $autoloader = new static($dir, $ext);
        spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);

        return $autoloader;
    }

    public function load($class)
    {
        $dir = $this->dir;

        if ($ns = $this->get_namespace($class)) {
            $dir .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $ns);
        }

        $inc_file = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$this->get_class($class).$this->ext;

        if (file_exists($inc_file)) {
            require_once $inc_file;
        }
    }

    // Borrowed from github.com/borisguery/Inflexible
    protected static function get_class($value)
    {
        $className = trim($value, '\\');

        if ($lastSeparator = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
            $className = substr($className, 1 + $lastSeparator);
        }

        return $className;
    }

    // Borrowed from github.com/borisguery/Inflexible
    public static function get_namespace($fqcn)
    {
        if ($lastSeparator = strrpos($fqcn, '\\')) {
            return trim(substr($fqcn, 0, $lastSeparator + 1), '\\');
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```

run.php

```
<?php

/* Register a basic autoloader */
require_once 'AutoLoader.php';
AutoLoader::register('src');

/* Create a packer */
$packer = new \Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker();

/* Create some test boxes */
$boxes = [];
// Create your boxes here

/* Add boxes to packer */
$packer->addBoxes($boxes);

/* Create some test items */
$items = [];
// Create your items here

/* Add items to packer */
$packer->addItems($items);

/* Pack */
$packed_boxes = $packer->pack();

/* Output - var_dump is fine */
var_dump($packed_boxes);
```

i understand that the require statement in run.php loads the autoloader.php script but that is the only thing about this which makes sense to me.

my questions are as follows

1)
what does `AutoLoader::register('src');` do?

2) 
`$packer = new \Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker();` creates a new packer object, but what is this object? the autoloader.php file does not make any reference to `\Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker().`

3)
The lines `$packer->addBoxes($boxes);`, `$packer->addItems($items);`, `$packer->pack();` seam to call the methods `addBoxes()`, `addItems()` and `pack()` of the instance of a class referenced to by `$packer`.

However none of these methods appear in the autoloader class in the `autoloader.php` file. and even if they did, `$packer` references an instance of `\Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker` not an instance of autoloader.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

1. Re-view http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php this one
2. Are you using some framework or another auto-loaders presented?
3. Disable this code and look will it work without or not

   require_once 'AutoLoader.php';
   AutoLoader::register('src');
4. If code will work without this autoloader - class exist by namespace it called
5. In this case read more about namespaces and all around

PS: Creating new class (I think) avoiding your autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

1. `AutoLoader::register('src');` instantiated a new instance of the
   `Autoload` class, providing the `src` directory as a parameter, and then

   ```
   spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);
   ```

   registers the `load` method in the `Autoloader` class as an
   implementation of
   [`__autoload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php)
2. Now when you attempt to use a class that has not been defined in
   scope, because you have registered an autoloader, it will attempt to
   look for the class in the `src` directory using the `load` method in the `Autoloader`
   class. If the autoloader finds the class, it uses PHP's `include`
   method to bring the class into scope so that you can then
   instantiate a new instance of it.
3. The methods you mention are defined in the
   `\Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker` class

Answer (score 0):

> 1) what does AutoLoader::register('src'); do?

It creates new AutoLoader class and it registers class method `load` as autoloader, equivalent to

```
$autoloader = new AutoLoader('src');
spl_autoload_register([$autoloader, 'load']);
```

from now on new autoloader has been registered (method `$autoloader->load()` is new autoloader)

`src` is folder where classes are located

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

> 2) $packer = new \Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker(); creates a
>   new packer object, but what is this object? the autoloader.php file
>   does not make any reference to
>   \Candidate\BoxPacker\DeveloperTestPacker().

`$packer` is class autoloaded from `src/Candidate/BoxPacker/DeveloperTestPacker.php`

> 3) The lines $packer->addBoxes($boxes);, $packer->addItems($items);,
>   $packer->pack(); seam to call the methods addBoxes(), addItems() and
>   pack() of the instance of a class referenced to by $packer.

see `src/Candidate/BoxPacker/DeveloperTestPacker.php`

Answer (score 0):

1) You register the folder src as a folder to look into (looking for class files to include)

2) can't answer with what you provided

3) same thing

the purpose of this script is do avoid bothering with include, you just write new MyClass(); if php throw an error it'll look into src folder trying to find the file who has the class MyClass.

I prefer mine(source : http://www.croes.org/gerald/blog/autoloader-php-universel-jouons-avec-les-patterns/77/) --> because it'll create a cache file. It's more suited from a performance POV.

```
    <?php

class ExtensionFilterIteratorDecorator extends FilterIterator {

    private $_ext;

    public function accept() {
        if (substr($this->current(), -1 * strlen($this->_ext)) === $this->_ext) {
            return is_readable($this->current());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function setExtension($pExt) {
        $this->_ext = $pExt;
    }

}

class DirectoriesAutoloaderException extends Exception {

}

class DirectoriesAutoloader {

    //--- Singleton
    private function __construct() {

    }

    private static $_instance = false;

    public static function instance($pTmpPath) {
        if (self::$_instance === false) {
            self::$_instance = new DirectoriesAutoloader();
            self::$_instance->setCachePath($pTmpPath);
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    //--- /Singleton
    //--- Cache
    private $_cachePath;

    public function setCachePath($pTmp) {
        if (!is_dir($pTmp))
        {
            throw new DirectoriesAutoloaderException('Cannot find in given CachePath [' . $pTmp . ']');
        }
        if (!is_writable($pTmp)) {
            throw new DirectoriesAutoloaderException('Cannot write in given CachePath [' . $pTmp . ']');
        }
        $this->_cachePath = $pTmp;
    }

    //--- /Cache
    //--- Autoload
    public function autoload($pClassName) {
        //On regarde si on connais la classe
        if ($this->_loadClass($pClassName)) {
            return true;
        }

        //Si on a le droit de tenter la regénération du fichier d'autoload, on retente l'histoire
        if ($this->_canRegenerate) {
            $this->_canRegenerate = false; //pour éviter que l'on
            $this->_includesAll();
            $this->_saveInCache();
            return $this->autoload($pClassName);
        }
        //on a vraiment rien trouvé.
        return false;
    }

    private $_canRegenerate = true;

    //--- /Autoload

    /**
     * Recherche de toutes les classes dans les répertoires donnés
     */
    private function _includesAll() {
        //Inclusion de toute les classes connues
        foreach ($this->_directories as $directory => $recursive) {
            $directories = new AppendIterator ();

            //On ajoute tous les chemins à parcourir
            if ($recursive) {
                $directories->append(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)));
            } else {
                $directories->append(new DirectoryIterator($directory));
            }

            //On va filtrer les fichiers php depuis les répertoires trouvés.
            $files = new ExtensionFilterIteratorDecorator($directories);
            $files->setExtension('.php');

            foreach ($files as $fileName) {
                $classes = $this->_extractClasses((string) $fileName);
                foreach ($classes as $className => $fileName) {
                    $this->_classes[strtolower($className)] = $fileName;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Extraction des classes & interfaces d'un fichier
     */
    private function _extractClasses($pFileName) {
        $toReturn = array();
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($pFileName, false));
        $tokens = array_filter($tokens, 'is_array');

        $classHunt = false;
        foreach ($tokens as $token) {
            if ($token[0] === T_INTERFACE || $token[0] === T_CLASS) {
                $classHunt = true;
                continue;
            }

            if ($classHunt && $token[0] === T_STRING) {
                $toReturn[$token[1]] = $pFileName;
                $classHunt = false;
            }
        }

        return $toReturn;
    }

    private $_classes = array();

    private function _saveIncache() {
        $toSave = '<?php $classes = ' . var_export($this->_classes, true) . '; ?>';
        file_put_contents($this->_cachePath . 'directoriesautoloader.cache.php', $toSave);
    }

    /**
     * Tente de charger une classe
     */
    private function _loadClass($pClassName) {
        $className = strtolower($pClassName);
        if (count($this->_classes) === 0) {
            if (is_readable($this->_cachePath . 'directoriesautoloader.cache.php')) {
                require ($this->_cachePath . 'directoriesautoloader.cache.php');
                $this->_classes = $classes;
            }
        }
        if (isset($this->_classes[$className])) {
            require_once ($this->_classes[$className]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Ajoute un répertoire a la liste de ceux à autoloader
     */
    public function addDirectory($pDirectory, $pRecursive = true) {
        if (!is_readable($pDirectory)) {
            throw new DirectoriesAutoloaderException('Cannot read from [' . $pDirectory . ']');
        }
        $this->_directories[$pDirectory] = $pRecursive ? true : false;
        return $this;
    }

    private $_directories = array();

}
```

usage :

```
$autoloader = DirectoriesAutoloader::instance($config['base_path'] . 'cache/')->addDirectory($config['base_path'] . 'load')->addDirectory($config['base_path'] . 'site/Modules')->addDirectory($config['base_path'] . 'site/Elements');
spl_autoload_register(array($autoloader, 'autoload'));
```